# Google Apps Script replaceText() not working with apostrophe " ' "

Tags: javascript, regex, string, google-apps-script

In my code, when I am trying to replace "don't" with "do not", it doesn't work, but when I use a regular word, it does. I have tried to escape with "don\'t".
Is there a special way to escape characters in google apps script?

```
//Sidebar.html
function doWordReplace(value) { 
   if(value.checked) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(print).wordReplace("don't");
   }
   else {}
}

//Replace.gs
function wordReplace(findMe) {
    var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText();
    text.replaceText(findMe, "do not");
  return "replacement successful";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of `replaceText()`

```
function wordReplace(findMe) {
    var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();

    // Use Unicode for right single quotation mark
    // \u2018-left single, \u2019-right single, \u0027-apostrophe
    text.replace(/don\u2019t/gi, "do not");
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().setText(text);

  return "replacement successful";
}
```

Comment: replace isn't a function in Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: It's javascript that is available in google apps script projects. Just tested it again in a new sheets script & stand alone scripts project.

Comment: ok so that means I need to get the text Object as a String first correct?

Comment: Looks like  it should probably be `var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText()` and then `.setText(text)`. I havent used `DocumentApp()` methods and figured that was a string you were retrieving.

Comment: it's still not working for me. With replace(), it still won't let me replace words with an apostrophe, but regular words do work.

Comment: Updated to use unicode character in the replace() for the `'`. Tested in Document script project. Seems like the script types out an apostrophe but the Document writes a right or left single quote...it was looking for a character that had not actually been used

Comment: Ok that really helped. I didn't know that docs replaces the apostrophe ( ' ) with a right single quote ( ’ ). I actually just replaced the character in my original code with the character and it worked. Thanks body.replaceText("don’t", "do not");